# Infragistics - Set Excel Cell Backgroundcolor

Tags: c#, excel, cell, background-color, infragistics

I need to color some Excel cells with my C# application.
The next "must have" is: I have to do this with the infragistics reference.

I was able to paint some cells:

```
worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].CellFormat.FillPatternBackgroundColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
```

but there is a grey pattern which makes the reading of the cells really hard. Is there any solution how I can take those grey patterns away?
I couldn't find any backgroundcolor attribute except this FillPatternBackgroundColor...

Greez Arion

Comment: ok - I might just don't get that becasue it's C# related, but just so you know - there is `CellFormat` in VBA, but no `FillPatternBackgroundColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;` - you would most likely format a cells background like I did in my example. Sorry, can't help you further.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a version prior to 12.1, set the fill pattern to solid:

```
worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].CellFormat.FillPattern = FillPatternStyle.Solid;
```

If you're on 12.1, those properties of been marked obsolete in favor of the Fill property:

```
worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].CellFormat.Fill = new CellFillPattern(new WorkbookColorInfo(Color.DarkSeaGreen), null, FillPatternStyle.Solid);
```

Comment: Seriously? How should I ever find that out? xD
Thank you very much! The second example worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Infragistics, the land of a million properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].interior.color = rgb(0,255,0)
```

or this:

```
worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].interior.colorindex = 3
```

Comment: I think for this solution I would use the standard Excel reference which requires that Office Excel to be installed that the code runs.
Anyway it would work for sure but I can't use it... "ABB Standards" -.-

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone who views this will probably know this, but to add to this answer; to set the color if you only have the RGB using the Infragistics Excel you can do this as well:

`worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[col].CellFormat.Fill = CellFill.CreateSolidFill(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0))`

(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) I believe the alpha(opacity) it always ignored by excel so don't let that throw you off.

I am using 2015.2.